# How to get Fluent NHibernate working with NHibernate 3.x

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to get Fluent NHibernate working with latest NHibernate 3.x trunk

I got the following Exception :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies.
```

EDIT :

This exception occurs in FluentNhibernate file PersistanceConfiguration

```
    public TThisConfiguration Cache(Action<CacheSettingsBuilder> cacheExpression)
    {
        cacheExpression(cache);
        return (TThisConfiguration)this;
    }
```

Don't understand, FluentNHibernate is well compiled against NH 3.x

Comment: What error are you getting?  It worked fine for me last time I tried it a few months ago.

Comment: @Michael : See edit of my question, i got that exception

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The FluentNHibernate [download page](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) has stable pre-release (pre 1.2) binaries for NHibernate 3.0 and 2.1.2

Comment: @Lachlan : I already did ... but still assembly load exception. I'm using it on an ASP.NET MVC web site. Maybe i need to clear ASP.NET temporary files ?

Comment: @Lachlan : cleared asp.net temporary files, exception still here

Comment: @Yoann Check the references of your fluent dll in reflector. If this shows NH 3.x, then something else is trying to load 2.1 - possibly from a web.config entry.

Comment: @Lachlan : References in FluentNhib are NH 3.x, however execption thrown into FluentNHibernate.cfg.Db.PersistenceConfirguration at line 190

        public TThisConfiguration Cache(Action<CacheSettingsBuilder> cacheExpression)
        {
            cacheExpression(cache);
            return (TThisConfiguration)this;
        }

Comment: @Yoann I think you might have a NH cache provider from NH2.1

Comment: @Lachlan : You right ! Now i' getting exception from NHibernate.Search, i'm going to rebuild it against NH 3.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Fluent just posted [pre-release binaries (v1.2)](http://fluentnhibernate.org/dls/v1.x/fluentnhibernate-NH3.0-binary-1.2.0.694.zip) with NH3 support. No need to recompile its sources.

Comment: do you know when v1.2 is going to be officially released?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( you can try to contact developers directly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd grab it from github:

https://github.com/dagda1/horn_src

this will include all of the dependancies also so you don't need to mess about with compiling all the projects and their dependancies :)

Comment: you can still download the code from google code and run it locally - it was never just about the website :) but there are also now alternatives - openwrap for one...